# How to create AppLink URL Facebook V4.0 in android ( Invite Friends )

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I have been following [Facebook developer reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) for sharing app to Facebook friend.

Also followed [This reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content)

I created AppLink URL with reference of Facebook Host API.

Now by this time I am able to get success for Facebook share but shared data is not reflected over Facebook Friend Wall.

I believe the main problem is that I am not able to create AppLink for it.

May you guys please assist me that how exactly we need to create that as this is not well documented over Facebook Developer site.

Looking ahead for any solution over this.

Comment: Maybe the problem lies in that your app is unapproved/ not open for general public. Having said that its just a guess. I second on the quality of FB's documentation, its very poor.

Comment: Please provide more info on what you did (the app link url you created, any code on how you're doing the share). Also, what do you mean by "shared data is not reflected on ... wall)?

Comment: Thanks Skynet & Ming Li. @Skynet I believe that there's no need to get approval in case of Tagging Friends as we are using their dialog. By sharing data I mean that tag is not reflected over my friends wall.